# Bash syntax help - mapfile/readarray (split text into array)

Tags: bash, syntax

In bash, in some StackOverflow answers they show how to populate the results to find files into an array:

### Info 1

Older bash versions

```
mapfile -d $'\0' array < <(find . -name "${input}" -print0)
```

OR newer bash versions: (4.2+)

```
readarray -d '' array < <(find . -name "$input" -print0)
```

### Info 2

Then there is also this to split a string into an array **but this doesn't work for me.**

```
readarray -d '|' PORTS <<< "${matched}"
```

I use this successfully, but this is *older syntax*.

```
IFS='|' read -r -a PORTS <<< $matched
```

Those answers do not explain the full syntax though:

**Can someone please explain:**

**Info 1**:

What is the the `<` bracket just before the normal `(` bracket doing?  If I add a `space` and/or replace that with a `$` then the command fails.  But I would like to understand what that is doing.

**Info 2**:

Somewhere I found this syntax for `readarray`, but it doesn't work for me, so it could be the same issue with the bracket `<` placements. How to use it correctly?

Comment: for `<( ... )` see [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution), for readarray see [mapfile](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile), `-t` may be useful to remove the delimiter

Comment: I am aware of `$( ... )` subprocess, but I thought the `<` might just be an alternative character.  Do you have a good resource where I can read more please?

Comment: Thank you, your updated comment with the links are clear.  I see what it means now, and it also explains that you can't use a space (as I tried) because then the meaning becomes different.

Comment: `-d` is an option for read, but not [readarray aka mapfile](https://ss64.com/bash/mapfile.html). You would need to use something like `IFS='|' readarray PORTS <<< "$matched"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not received an answer which I would have upvoted.  To answer the question for **Info 1**, in case the link ever expires that Nahuel gave, the relevant part.  This is important for me because sometimes I would like to *understand what a given solution does, and sometimes that part is not explained in answers.*

Its called *Process Substitution*

### Process Substitution

Process substitution allows a process’s input or output to be referred to using a filename. It takes the form of

```
<(list)
```

or

```
>(list)
```

#### Functionality

> The process  list  is run asynchronously, and its input or output appears as a *filename*. This filename is passed as an argument to the current command as the result of the expansion.
>
> - If the  `>(list)`  form is used, *writing to the file will provide input for **list***.
> - If the  `<(list)`  form is used, the file passed as an argument *should be read to obtain the output of **list***.

#### Regarding my question about spaces

> Note that no space may appear between the  `<`  or  `>`  and the left parenthesis, otherwise the construct would be interpreted as a redirection. Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the  /dev/fd  method of naming open files.

When available, process substitution is performed simultaneously with parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.

I still need clarification on **Info 2** though.